# Break a polygon into small pieces or triangles

Tags: game-physics, sprite-kit

I'm starting with the sprite-kit framework and i want to know if it's possible to break a square, for example, into triangles or other small polygons.

I know how to detect collision between a bullet and a basic polygon, but is defined any method in Sprite-kit to divide or split a polygon into small ones ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

i don't believe that there is.  I believe that this is the purpose of joints.  You create the individual bodies, then join them together with fixed joints.  The joined bodies act as one, until you decide to break some or all of the joints.

This page has details on creating joints:
https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsJoint_Ref/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 1):

You probably might want to use something like [this](http://dazchong.com/spritekit/) tool.
It allows you to define `physicsBody` with a custom shape, for example:

```
SKSpriteNode *sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"img"];

CGFloat offsetX = sprite.size.width * self.anchorPoint.x;
CGFloat offsetY = sprite.size.height * self.anchorPoint.y;

CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();

CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, 24 - offsetX, 124 - offsetY);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 24 - offsetX, 47 - offsetY);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 339 - offsetX, 1 - offsetY);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 401 - offsetX, 3 - offsetY);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 452 - offsetX, 52 - offsetY);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 411 - offsetX, 78 - offsetY);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 295 - offsetX, 78 - offsetY);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 268 - offsetX, 93 - offsetY);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 95 - offsetX, 78 - offsetY);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 62 - offsetX, 124 - offsetY);

CGPathCloseSubpath(path);

sprite.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithPolygonFromPath:path];
```

Comment: Woahh, great answer. Tomorrow i will test your answer. Thanks.